# How to plot CDF of a Poisson distribution in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions

How to plot the following in *Mathematica*:

$$P = \sum_{k=C+1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-C^\gamma} (C^\gamma)^k}{k!}$$

I want to plot $P$ versus $C \log{C}$ for a given $\gamma$ with logarithmic scale on Y-axis. In MATLAB, I'd calculate it as follows:

```matlab
gamma = 0.75;
C = 1:1:20;
lambda = C .^ gamma;
p = 1 - poisscdf(C,lambda);
semilogy(C .* log(C), p);
```

Comment: You probably could have worked this out by searching in the documentation for "poisson distribution", yielding [`PoissonDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PoissonDistribution.html), and "log plot", yielding a range of hits including [`ListLogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListLogPlot.html), [`LogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LogPlot.html) etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is worth noting two characteristic features of the question:

1. The sum is a complementary cumulative distribution function for a Poisson distribution: it's built in to *Mathematica* and needn't be computed explicitly.
2. The use of $C+1$ as a starting index in the sum, as well as the expression `1:1:20` in the code, indicate $C$ is considered an integer: this needs to be a *discrete* plot.

It can also help to draw clear parallels between the ΜATLAB approach and an idiomatic *Mathematica* approach.  How about this?

```
Module[{c = Range[20], γ = 0.75, p},
 p = {# Log[#], 1 - CDF[PoissonDistribution[#^γ], #]} & /@ c;
 ListLogPlot[p]
]
```

[image: Log linear plot]

Comment: Much easier now. But, what about the logarithmic scale on the y-axis? I mean the ticks!

Comment: @Osama They *are* logarithmic!

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I would do:

```
p[c_, x_] = (Sum[Exp[-x] x^k/k!, {k, c + 1, Infinity}] // 
   FullSimplify)

With[{gamma = 0.75}, 
 ParametricPlot[{c Log[c], p[c, c^gamma]}, {c, 1, 20}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: How to make it logarithmic scale on y axes as in the Matlab code? I used Log[p[c, c^gamma]] but still can't edit the axes thing!!

Comment: cValues = Range[1, 20, 0.05];
ListLogPlot[{# Log[#], p[#, #^0.75]} & /@ cValues, PlotRange -> All] ?

Comment: Why things is much complicated in Mathematica than in Matlab!

Comment: Here's a more compact definition of `p[c, x]`: `p[c_, x_] := GammaRegularized[c + 1, 0, x]`. I don't understand why `FullSimplify[]` doesn't use `GammaRegularized[]` more frequently myself...

Answer (score 3):

This is only a minor variant on the existing answers, but it will hopefully be clearer to a novice user:

```
pp[c_?Positive, γ_] := {c Log[c], 1 - CDF[PoissonDistribution[c^γ], c]}
ListLogPlot[Table[pp[x, 0.75], {x, 1, 40}]]
```

[image]

But notice:

```
ListLogPlot[Table[pp[x, 0.75], {x, 1, 40, 0.02}], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

The function is defined for non-integer values of $c$, but includes a `Floor` expression.

```
Assuming[c > 0, Simplify[1 - CDF[PoissonDistribution[c^γ], c]]]
(*  ==> 1 - GammaRegularized[1 + Floor[c], c^γ]  *)
```

As J.M. pointed out in comments, the expression that results from this simplification can be further simplified to `GammaRegularized[1 + Floor[c], 0, c^γ]`, but the presence of `Floor[]` in the result is clear even in the less-simplified version.

Comment: Again: `1 - GammaRegularized[1 + Floor[c], c^γ]` can be simplified further to `GammaRegularized[1 + Floor[c], 0, c^γ]`. Numerically, it's a good idea to be using the three-argument form `GammaRegularized[]` for situations like this...